# LINQ Join statement with possible NULL id?

Tags: linq, null

I have a LINQ statement where I am joining on an ID field.  The problem is that sometimes the ID on the left of the "equals" may be null.
Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: LINQ to Objects? LINQ to SQL? What's happening at the moment, and what do you *want* to happen?

Comment: LINQ-to-Objects.  Right now it is giving an error that the value is NULL, I want it to just join on the rows that match.  This is on a LEFT OUTER Join.

Comment: can you post your linq query?

Comment: As I've said in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109630/linq-join-inside-join-how-to), you need to resolve the null values before trying to join...

Comment: @jeff, this is actually a completely unrelated issue. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from x in left
where x.Id != null
join y in right on x.Id equals y.Id into rightMatches
from y2 in rightMatches.DefaultIfEmpty()  //in your comments you said LEFT JOIN
select new {x, y2};
```